# VBA inheritance

Tags: vba, inheritance

I heard a lot of that VBA is lacking inheritance. I did a little workaround and now it seems to me that it is exactly what inheritance does. I'm far from pro =) and may be missing something. So I would really appreciate your thoughts about possible downsides.

I was very surprised when found that you still can make a full realization of a function in an interface class (not only a signature), which led me to the following below. I saw that some people did similar with help of composition, but they used only a signature in the interface.

IBird - class

```
Public Sub SayFromInterface()
    Debug.Print "Tweet from IBird"
End Sub

Public Sub SayFromInstance()
End Sub
```

Crow - class

```
Implements IBird

Private pBird As IBird

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pBird = New IBird
End Sub

'let you use already implemented code from "abstract class", to avoid
'duplicating your code, which is the main point of inheritance
'in my opinion
Public Sub IBird_SayFromInterface()
    pBird.SayFromInterface
End Sub

'you can override the IBird function (common use)
Public Sub IBird_SayFromInstance()
    Debug.Print "Tweet from Crow"
End Sub
```

Test - module

```
Sub testIBird()

 Dim Bird As IBird

 Set Bird = New Crow

 Bird.SayFromInterface
 Bird.SayFromInstance
 Debug.Print TypeName(Bird)
 Debug.Print TypeOf Bird Is IBird

End Sub
```

Output:

```
Tweet from IBird
Tweet from Crow
Crow
True
```

Comment: Why declare `As New IBird` only to immediately wipe that reference with a `New Crow`? Just declare `As IBird`.

Comment: My bad, didn't clean the code properly after playing. Thank you for your comment. Will edit the post.

Comment: I was surprised to see that VBA can implement interfaces, but I guess that is expected from COM programming. We are so familiar with interfaces now with C# and VB.NET that we forget that the .NET Framework was originally an extension to COM programming called COM+.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - very cool. Do you use `SourceTools.xla` to extract the source files from Excel? Or is there functionality in Rubberduck to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's *composition*, not inheritance - and yes, with composition you can essentially emulate inheritance. And if the class implements the interface of the encapsulated object, then things start looking like some kind of a *decorator* pattern.

Except you wouldn't be having any implementation code in `IBird`. An interface should be purely abstract. Making a `New` instance of what's supposed to be an interface, makes the class no longer be an interface: now it's just another class exposing a default interface that any other class can implement, and the `I` prefix becomes rather confusing:

> ```
> Set pBird = New IBird
> ```

It's rather weird that the client code now needs to wonder whether they want that bird to chirp `FromInstance` or `FromInterface` - these are very "meta" identifiers that make things *not* work like inheritance.

If we had a `Crow : Bird` where `Bird` had this implementation for `IBird.Chirp`:

```csharp
public virtual string Chirp() => "Chirp!";
```

...and then `Crow` had this:

```csharp
public override string Chirp() => "Craaaw!";
```

Then which method is invoked depends on what the *runtime type* is - this should feel pretty obvious:

```csharp
IBird bird1 = new Bird();
bird1.Chirp(); // "Chirp!"

IBird bird2 = new Crow();
bird2.Chirp(); // "Craaaw!"
```

However picture a method that receives an `IBird` parameter:

```csharp
public void DoSomething(IBird bird)
{
    Debug.Print(bird.Chirp());
}
```

If `bird` is a `Bird`, it prints "Chirp!"; if `bird` is a `Crow`, it prints "Craaaw!": the method that gets to run, is the most derived override, *which isn't necessarily defined on the most derived type*.

Inheritance would allow a `GiantCrow : Crow` to inherit the `Chirp` method from `Crow` and *not necessarily* override it. And *that* is what you can't simulate with VBA classes: you are forced to write the equivalent of...

```csharp
public override string Chirp() => base.Chirp();
```

...which is technically redundant, and gets very repetitive if you have to do it every time just to get the "base" members visible on your default interface.

Instead of *inheriting* base members, we actually *wrap* calls to the encapsulated object. The *decorator* pattern does exactly that, and gives you a non-intrusive way of extending a VBA class or interface.

A decorator implements the interface it's extending, and encapsulates a private instance of that type. So basically with a decorator the "crow inheritance hierarchy" setup looks like this:

```
Dim bird As IBird
Set bird = Crow.Create(New BaseBird)
```

A perhaps more suitable decorator pattern example might be:

```
Dim repository As IRepository
Set repository = LoggingRepository.Create(BirdRepository.Create(connectionString), New DebugLogger)
```

Where a `BirdRepository` is responsible for abstracting the database operations relating to some `Birds` table (`BirdRepository` implements `IRepository`), and where `LoggingRepository` is a *decorator* that *also* implements `IRepository`, but also wraps an `IRepository` instance (in this case a `BirdRepository`) to add its own functionality - something that might look like this:

```
'@PredeclaredId
Implements IRepository
Private loggerInternal As ILogger
Private wrappedInternal As IRepository

Public Function Create(ByVal internal As IRepository, ByVal logger As ILogger) As IRepository
    Dim result As LoggingRepository
    Set result.Wrapped = internal
    Set result.Log = logger
    Set Create = result
End Function 

Public Property Get Wrapped() As IRepository
    Set Wrapped = wrappedInternal
End Property

Public Property Set Wrapped(ByVal value As IRepository)
    If Not wrappedInternal Is Nothing Then Err.Raise 5, TypeName(Me), "Instance is already initialized."
    Set wrappedInternal = value
End Property

Public Property Get Log() As ILogger
    Set Log = loggerInternal
End Property

Public Property Set Log(ByVal value As ILogger)
    If Not loggerInternal Is Nothing Then Err.Raise 5, TypeName(Me), "Instance is already initialized."
    Set loggerInternal = value
End Property

Private Function IRepository_SelectAll() As Object
    Log.Info "Starting IRepository.SelectAll"
    Dim t As Double
    t = Timer

    Set IRepository_SelectAll = wrappedInternal.SelectAll

    Log.Info "IRepository.SelectAll completed in " & Timer - t & " seconds."
End Function

Private Sub IRepository_Delete(ByVal id As Long)
    Log.Info "Starting IRepository.Delete(" & id & ")"
    Dim t As Double
    t = Timer

    wrappedInternal.Delete id

    Log.Info "IRepository.Delete completed in " & Timer - t & " seconds."
End Sub

Private Sub IRepository_Save(ByVal entity As Object)
    '...
    wrappedInternal.Save entity
    '...
End Sub

'...
```

A method that is given a `IRepository` object cannot (and absolutely *should* not) know whether it's given a plain `BirdRepository`, a `LoggingRepository` wrapping a `BirdRepository`, or a `FakeRepository` that encapsulates a `Collection` instead of access to a database table - and this polymorphism is the entire point.

It's one way to extend a type without using inheritance, that VBA can absolutely leverage without bastardizing the pattern too much. But it's not inheritance.